# React router is not taking ID in Link

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I am working on project which is based on Firebase and React JS, i want to set ID in Link in Route Component but its returning me undefined,
It goes like, first List of Trainers Page and then Edit Trainer (specifically)
Main Component Look like this where i am giving my routes

```
<Route path= '/listOfTrainers' component={ListOfztrainers} />
<Route path='/editTrainer/:UID' component={EditTrainer} />
```

Then there is a list of trainer page, where i am showing list of trainer in table. One of its column in Edit Profile where i am giving link like below

```
Cell: <Link to= {`/editTrainer/${trainer.UID}`}>Edit</Link>
```

When i click on any trainer's row Edit Profile, it return me undefined in url

[image]

And when my self add ID which is firebase UID in url, it gives me correct result like

[image]

I am dropping code below of edit Trainer,

```
componentDidMount(){
      const id = this.props.match.params.UID;
      console.log(id);
      firebase.database().ref(`Users/Trainers/` + id).on('value', (snapshot) => {
          var trainer = snapshot.val();
          this.setState ({
            trainer
          }, console.log(trainer))
      })
    }
```

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong here in routing

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem you need to make sure that your `trainer` data fetched and parsed on DOM correctly like so :

```
componentDidMount(){
      const id = this.props.match.params.UID;
      console.log(id);
      firebase.database().ref(`Users/Trainers/` + id).on('value', (snapshot) => {
          var trainer = snapshot.val();
          this.setState ({
            trainer
          }, console.log(trainer))
      })
    }


render() {
 let {trainer} = this.state;
 return (
    <>
    // in this way you can make sure that data parsed correctly on your dom elements
    {trainer && <Link to= {`/editTrainer/${trainer.UID}`}>Edit</Link>}
    </>

    )
}
```

Comment: does your trainer log from console.log ?